# Algorithm for multiple circle-circle collisions

Tags: algorithm, matlab, collision-detection

I have a bit of a stump on how to detect collisions of here we're only using vectors of data and no classes (I know classes have been implemented but I'm not allowed to use them).

So, how do I even do this? There are some examples on the internet but they only look at two circles. I have a user-defined amount of circles (balls). So do I need to determine which ones are the of closest distance, and if yes how? I'm so confused on how to start with this.

So far I can create a certain amount of circles in random position on the screen and make them move in the same direction (that's fine). All balls are of the same radius and have the same speed.

Here's the major part of the code:

```
N_balls = input('Enter the amount of balls: ');
radius = input('Enter radius for all balls: ');

for i = 1:N_balls

   x_init(i) = randi([27, 550]);
   y_init(i) = randi([27, 400]);

end

for i = 1:N_balls

    ball(i) = drawBall(x_init(i), y_init(i), radius, 'r');

end

% Initialize a loop control variable
exit_loop = false;

x = [];
y = [];

velocity_x = 1;
velocity_y = 1;

distance = [];

% While is not commanded to exit the loop
while exit_loop == false

for i = 1:N_balls

    [x(i), y(i)] = getCenter(ball(i));

    xMove(ball(i), velocity_x);
    yMove(ball(i), velocity_y);

    redraw;
end

for i = 2:N_balls

    distance(i-1) = sqrt( ((x(i-1) - x(i)) * (x(i-1) - x(i))) + (        (y(i-1) - y(i)) * (y(i-1) - y(i)) ) );

end

[dist, ball_num] = min(distance);
end
```

It's a mess but yeah, I'm lost here...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to determine one the closest pair: [well-known problem of computational geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem)

If you need to find all pairs with distance below some limit, then you need some space-partitioning data structure, for example, [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)